# How to get custom attribute value in jquery or JS from radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-attributes

I got a piece of HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onChange="rdbtn()" value="100" isprm="true">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onChange="rdbtn()" value="110" isprm="true">
```

and I want to pass the custom attribute value into a variable. Here is what I tried and does not work:

```
function rdbtn(){
   var radioVal = $(this).val();
   var radioPRM = $("input[id=radioVal]:checked").attr('isprm');
   ...
}
```

and

```
$('input[id=radioVal]').data("isprm");
```

No luck. Do you have any ideas how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: if you want to use `.data()` the attribute has to be `data-isprm="true"`

Comment: @TheKolanN: Which jquery version you are using?

Comment: @JeffShaver: I use jQuery 2.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `isprm` is not a valid attribute so your HTML is invalid. If you need to store ancillary data with an element use a `data-*` attribute:

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onChange="rdbtn()" value="100" data-isprm="true">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onChange="rdbtn()" value="110" data-isprm="true">
```

You can then use `data()` to retrieve the value:

```
var radioPRM = $('input[name="radioBtn"]:checked').data('isprm');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix `data-` with custom attributes to work with `.data()`. Also you have to use `name` when using attribute value selector since you have not specified `id` of radio option and use name which you have specified i.e. `radioBtn`

Use

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onChange="rdbtn()" value="110" data-isprm="true">
```

Then

```
$('input[name=radioBtn]').data("isprm");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9BuA3/)